# python xlsxwriter: conditional_format icon set and no cell icon

Tags: xlsxwriter

I have the requirement of using excel like  conditional_format icon set in xlsxwriter. It is working same like excel but I couldn't find an option to set "No cell icon".

Is there any option available  in xlsxwriter?

Below is the screenshot for reference:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70krb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any option available in xlsxwriter.

No. That functionality was added in a later version of the Xlsx format so it isn't supported by XlsxWriter.